# Two Sinatra Apps, shared datamapper DB

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I'm trying to think of a good way of using Sinatra and Datamapper to create a solid web app that shares a database. I started using just one app, but I'm thinking about splitting the admin aspect to it's own app with a different mapping in a config.ru file.

So, config.ru will map the root route to the main app, and '/admin' to the Admin app. The main app will be responsible for showing data from the db to any user, and the Admin app is responsible for allowing admins to add content to the db. My reasoning behind this is to allow me more flexibility and reusability with the admin app.

The main app has the Datamapper classes responsible for defining my model, though I am sure I could move that to the admin app without a problem. Is there a way/reason to move it to it's own separate .rb file?

Obviously new to this platform, but I'm loving it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one project with as many sinatra apps as you like. for your project, you can set it up like this:

```
# site.rb
require 'config/boot'
class Site < Sinatra::Base
  ...
end

# admin.rb
require 'config/boot'
class Admin < Sinatra::Base
  ...
end

# config/boot.rb
require 'model/user.rb'
require 'model/post.rb'

# config.ru
require 'admin'
require 'site'
run Rack::URLMap.new("/" => Site.new, "/admin" => Admin.new)
```

The key is to put both apps in the same project / version control.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to throw something together along these lines, but it makes sense. Thank you very much! Could you explain the "run Rack::URLMap.new..." line? I haven't seen a config.ru like this before...